# Is BatchNorm turned off when inferencing?

Tags: deep-learning, batch-normalization

I read from several sources that implicitly suggest batchnorm being turned off for inference but I have no definite answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Most common is to use a moving average of mean and std for your batch normalization as used by Keras for example (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py). If you just turn it off the network will perform worse on the same data, due to changes in how the images are processed.

This is done by storing the average mean and the average std of all the batches used during training the network. Then in inference this moving average is used for normalization.